# Monaco Editor change IntelliSense Behaviour

Tags: typescript, monaco-editor

I am experimenting with the CompletionItemProvider, I have two CompletionItemProvider's. One is triggered on all the alphabet letters and the other is triggered when the user types single quote character (').

But my goal would be that inside a double quote, for example ' here inside ', when the user hits <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> to activate the IntelliSense he only gets to see a specific completion provider, for example the down below. Is that possible ?

```
// should only trigger inside quotes
public areaCompletionProvider = <monaco.languages.CompletionItemProvider>{
    triggerCharacters: ['\''],
    provideCompletionItems: (model, position, token) => {
        let current = this.store[this.store.length - 1];
        if (!current) {
            return [];
        }

        let uniqueContextVariables: string[] = Array.from(new Set(current.contextVariables.map(ctxVariable => ctxVariable.area)));
        let areaCompletions = uniqueContextVariables.map(area => <monaco.languages.CompletionItem>{
            label: area,
            kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Field,
        });

        return areaCompletions;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a better solution but I managed to change the IntelliSense behaviour <kbd>CTRL+SPACE</kbd> inside a string (between two quotes).

I am using the findMatches method and with the help of Regular Expressions I am looking if I am inside a string. If that is the case I return.

```
// This is for completion of context variables and shortcuts
public variableCompletionProvider = <monaco.languages.CompletionItemProvider>{
    triggerCharacters: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split(''),
    provideCompletionItems: (model, position, token) => {

        // Check if inside string quotes, then don't offer variable completion as inside quotes only area completion should be available
        var quotes = model.findMatches(`'([^'])*'`, true, true, true, null, true);
        if (quotes.length > 0) {
            for (let quote of quotes) {
                if (quote && (position.column >= quote.range.startColumn && position.column <= quote.range.endColumn)) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

         // If I am not inside a string (quotes) then proceed with providing Completion 
         // Some more Code Here ...

    }
};
```

I am not sure if I can do it better. Also it won't work on a string that goes over more lines. For any suggestion I am thankful.